# Busqueda por coincidencia en sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

tengo la siguiente consulta.

Tengo un store procedure que recibe como parametro un nombre, por ejemplo: perez, fernando ezequiel.
tengo varias tablas con campos: APP,NOMBRE. lo que necesito es que en las tablas que el nombre que recibo como parametro choque con el campo NOMBRE de la tabla me devuelva APP. el problema es que en las tablas el nombre puede estar como: fernando ezequiel perez o perez fernando. necesito encontrar la coincidencia por palabras, independientemente de la organizacion de las palabras,pero nose como hacerlo. Aguardo sugerencias. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola Fernando, ya probaste con la sentencia `LIKE` de SQL? lo único que vería yo es que si tienes varias personas con el mismo nombre obtendrás multiples coincidencias y no se si esto sea lo que esperas (sino es así tendrías que obtener algún otro dato que te ayude a filtrar específicamente, ya sea por documento de identidad, teléfono, etc)

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

incluso puedes usar expresiones regulares con `like`

Comment: Buenas je corralez si probé pero no me trae, la idea que coincidan cada palabra, con like me funcionaria solo si es igual el nombre,